# funciones en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

```
def numeros(A, B, C):

    A = int(input("ingrese numero uno"))
    B = int(input(" ingrese numero dos"))
    C = int (input("ingrese numero tres"))
    return A, B, C

def numero_mayor(A, B, C):

    if(A > B and A > C):
        print("El numero mayor es ", A)
    elif (B > A and B > C):
        print("El numero mayor es ", B)
    else:
        print("El numero mayor es ", C)

numero_mayor(A, B, C)
```

Escribe código que solicite tres números por pantalla y que imprima el máximo de los 3 números. Para ello, define dos funciones. 
tengo problemas con el compilado del codigo y me tira error diciendo que A NO ESTA DEFINIDO

Comment: Corrige la indentación del código en tu pregunta, para que se pueda leer correctamente. De lo contrario no hay forma de saber si es que tu código tiene errores de indentación Lo más sencillo es que delimites los trozos de código poniendo una línea con ``` al principio y otra con ``` al final

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un gran lio con el paso por referencia y el scope (ambito) de tus variables (por cierto, por convención las variables siempre se han escrito en minusculas. Las mayusculas, por convención, están reservadas para constantes, aunque en Python no existan).

Varias cosas:

1. **Cuando llamas a la función números**?
2. **Donde guardas el valor de los numeros obtenidos por la función numeros**?

Lo que te comentaba, tienes un lio con el paso por referencia y el scope de tus variables.

Aunque en Python solo existe el paso por referencia (todo son objetos) hay objetos (como los int o los Strings) que son INMUTABLES, es decir, no se pueden modificar.

Debido a esto, cuando en tu función numeros haces algo como A = int(input("ingrese numero uno")), al ser A un entero definido dentro de una funcion, Python interpreta esto como la creacion de una nueva variable de ambito (scope) local que nada tiene que ver con el A del parametro de entrada. Y lo mismo para B y para C. Por lo tanto las variables A, B y C fuera de la función no van a ser modificadas.

**Haz esta prueba, mira lo que pasa y llega a una conclusión:**

```
A=0
B=0
C=0

print(A,B,C)

def numeros(A,B,C):

    A = int(input("ingrese numero uno"))
    B = int(input(" ingrese numero dos"))
    C = int(input("ingrese numero tres"))

    return A, B, C

numeros(A,B,C)

print(A,B,C)
```

**Aunque llamases a la función números (antes de llamar a numero_mayor, claro) las variables A, B y C quedan fuera del scope del "programa principal"**. Es decir, cuandos sales fuera de la función numeros A, B y C desaparecen.

Por lo tanto cuando llamas a la función numero_mayor las variables no se encuentran o no estan definidas.

La **solución** puede ser algo así:

```
def numeros():
    A = int(input("ingrese numero uno"))
    B = int(input(" ingrese numero dos"))
    C = int(input("ingrese numero tres"))
    return A, B, C


def numero_mayor(A, B, C):
    if (A > B and A > C):
        print("El numero mayor es ", A)
    elif (B > A and B > C):
        print("El numero mayor es ", B)
    else:
        print("El numero mayor es ", C)

a,b,c = numeros()
numero_mayor(a,b,c)
```